# Keycloak with springboot 3 basic and bearer authentication

Tags: keycloak, basic-authentication, spring-security-rest, spring-boot-3

Currently, I am using **KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** which manages basic and bearer token authentication using keaycloak for spring-boot rest API

now I am moving to Sprinboot 3, but seems **KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** has been deprecated, there are plenty of methods to implement with oath2 for bearer token validation but how to do basic authentication with users created in keycloak.